# how to add a List<List<String>> on a statement

Tags: apex, list

Hello there I just want to put same 3 statement on a List> row

List> [0] Statement 1 on a first row /
List> [1] Statement 2 on a second row /
List> [2] Statement 3 on a second row /

To This same value Row1:

```
List<List<String>> resultList1 = Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain');
```

Row2

```
List<List<String>> resultList1 = Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain');
```

Row3

```
List<List<String>> resultList1 = Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain');
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: what is return type of Cd_DocumentUploadController?

Comment: I Think List<List<String>> listCsvResult = new List<List<String>>();

Comment: so do u want to put all three results in new list?

Comment: yes All i want is,  add a List<List<String>> 's Size more than 1 row variable type List<List<String>> getUploadCls(String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use addAll method.

```
List<List<String>> resultList1 = new List<List<String>>();

List<List<String>> tempResult = Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain');
if (tempResult != null && tempResult.size() > 0) {
    resultList1.addAddAll(tempResult);
}

tempResult = Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain');
if (tempResult != null && tempResult.size() > 0) {
    resultList1.addAddAll(tempResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but that is adding totalResultsList's Size. i want to add List<List<String>> resultList1 's Size more than 1 . cuz debug keeps returning the resultList1's Size for 1 in order to get Test Coverage

Comment: Updated the answer plz check

Comment: it keep returns error so i had  removed if statement and replace it to  resultList1.addAll(tempResult);  but it goes saaaaaaammmee

Comment: Ohh! it was exclamation I added accidentally. Updated the code

Comment: remove the '!'  and it should work

Comment: probably your method is not returning it. try debugging `tempResult`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line, like this:

```
List<List<String>> resultList1 = new List<List<String>> { 
  Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain'),
  Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain'),
  Cd_DocumentUploadController.getUploadCls('testFileName', base64Value, 'text/plain')};
```

Comment: Thanks Aidan but itExpecting ';' but was: ',' (Line: 142, Column: 92)
classes/Cd_DocumentUploadController_Test.cls: Expecting ';' but was: ',' (Line: 143, Column: 92)
classes/Cd_DocumentUploadController_Test.cls: Extra ';', at '}'. (Line: 144, Column: 92)
classes/Cd_DocumentUploadController_Test.cls: Expecting '}' but was: '<EOF>' (Line: 224, Column: 1)